# Java parallel Streams processing time mismatch

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

On my windows machine, I have 6 cores.

I create a stream of 24 elements, and execute an operation on each element using map operation in Stream API. I make use of parallelism:

```
myCollection.parallelStream()
                    .map(element -> someTimeConsumingOperation(element)
                    .collect(toList());
```

someTimeConsumingOperation simulates long operation using:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

myCollection has 24 elements. I understand that streams use default ForkJoinPool executor to run operations in parallel, which in turn takes into account number of cores to determine how many threads to  have in the pool.

As there are 6 cores, so I assume max 6 threads are created. If that is the case, and every operation takes almost 2 seconds, entire stream processing must take around 8 seconds(each thread would execute 4 operations as we have 24 elements to process, hence 4*2 seconds).

But I observe that processing takes just 4 seconds.

Comment: Is your CPU from Intel and do you have hyper threading turned on? (If you haven't explicitly turned it off it's on)

Comment: Method `sleep()` in class `Thread` throws `InterruptedException`. Are you sure that each _time consuming operation_ runs for exactly two seconds?

Comment: I see there is something called 'Logical Processors' and it's value is 12. So with 24 elements, time is 4 seconds, but with 25 elements time is 6 seconds. This observation is in line with number of logical processors(12). I think this explains though not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your 6-core Intel CPU has [HyperThreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) enabled. With HT, the operating system and applications see each CPU core as 2 separate "logical cores" or "threads" (the nomenclature varies). This means `ForkJoinPool` will use 12 threads instead of 6.

The "logical cores" share some resources between each other, so running 12 tasks in parallel does not give you twice the throughput as running 6 tasks. But a program that only calls `sleep()` won't know the difference.